# How to insert data into tables using html forms instead of Django forms?

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm newbie in Django. I want to insert some data in my database tables from my html form and I actually don't want to use django forms, only simple form created in html file. I have no idea on how to do it is there any way to do it ? If yes , please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make a view to handle the POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle a POST request with POST parameters data1, data2, ... dataN, you can do something like this. This uses a class-based view (CBV).

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        do_something()
        return HttpResponse('GET Success!')

    def post(self, request):
        # Retrieve POST parameters
        data1 = request.POST.get('data1', '')
        data2 = request.POST.get('data2', '')
        # ...
        dataN = request.POST.get('dataN', '')

        # Perform whatever validations you need
        perform_validations()

        # Create your object based on validated user input.
        YourModel.objects.create(
            data1=data1,
            data2=data2,
            # ...
            dataN=dataN
        )

        # Do whatever else you need to.
        do_something_else()

        # Return a response.
        return HttpResponse('POST Success!')
```

You can also write one using function based views (FBV), but personally, I only use FBV's for easy testing of ideas or when it is a pain to use a CBV.

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        do_something()
        return HttpResponse('GET Success!')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Retrieve POST parameters
        data1 = request.POST.get('data1', '')
        data2 = request.POST.get('data2', '')
        # ...
        dataN = request.POST.get('dataN', '')

        # Perform whatever validations you need
        perform_validations()

        # Create your object based on validated user input.
        YourModel.objects.create(
            data1=data1,
            data2=data2,
            # ...
            dataN=dataN
        )

        # Do whatever else you need to.
        do_something_else()

        # Return a response.
        return HttpResponse('POST Success!')
```

Additional resources [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view), [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views), and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#view).

Comment: Thanks you that works perfectly , I have used the 2nd one .

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you have no further questions or clarifications, please accept this answer for the benefit of others as well! Thanks!